# i'm trying to find the number that is used only once in an array.

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//finds the number that is used only once
void t(int c, int a[]){
  int i,j;

for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<c;j++){
        if(a[i]==a[j]){
            a[i]=0;
            a[j]=0;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<c;i++){
 if(a[i]!=0)
  printf("%d\n",a[i]);
 }

}
```

Please find the mistake in t function because the compiler doesn't show any errors..

Is there something wrong with here?;

```
      if(a[i]==a[j]){
        a[i]=0;
        a[j]=0;
      }
```

Comment: Just throwing some buggy code at people, saying "Please find the mistake" is generally not considered *motivating* to people here at SO. So, please try to at least describe your problem and explain what you don't understand, if you do that, you'll find many helpful people here.

Comment: i'm not throwing some buggy code at you, i'm just not good at coding and that's my work. if i didn't try i wouldn't even put my code here i'd just say "please write a program that finds the number used only once in an array." so if you are not gonna help, don't bother your fingers to write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//finds the number that is used only once
void t(int c, int a[][2]){
  int i,j;

for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        if(a[i][0]==a[j][0] && i != j){
            a[i][1]=1;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<c;i++){
 if(a[i][1]==0)
  printf("%d\n",a[i][0]);
 }

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a[][2] = {{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{3,0},{2,0},{1,0},{3,0},{5,0},{5,0},{2,0},{3,0}};
    t(12, a);
}
```

I included a main to show intended calling. It does have the inefficiency of having to iterate from zero in both loops, but I can't quickly see how to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

If a number appears three times (say), then when you find the first pair you set them equal to zero; that means you can't find the third appearance.  If you know there's only supposed to be one unique number, you could perhaps count matches and then store the index if you get through the loop and don't find a match.

Comment: you're right i didn't think the possibility that there may be 3 or more repeating numbers. i just don't understand how to print the non-matched numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As modified by your policy.
(but Can not find a zero, the element is destroyed)

```
//finds the number that is used only once
void t(int c, int a[]){
    int i, j, find;

    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        if(a[i]==0)
            continue;
        find = 0;
        for(j=i+1;j<c;j++){
            if(a[i]==a[j]){
                find = 1;
                a[j]=0;
            }
        }
        if(find==0)
            printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        else
            a[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have wrong the parameters that you main function receives. Programs made in C language only receive two things: and int variable which is the number of parameters that you have passed, and a char* that is the list of parameters that you have passed by console. That is your problem.

Comment: i didn't put the main part here because the problem is in the function.